# Python Adafruit DHT11 error

Tags: python, rpi.gpio

I have a very simple Python program on my RPi0W to display DHT11 Temp and Pressure readings using SSH. I'm planning to build on it to develop a data logger using MySql. I tested the program and it worked fine.

sshlog.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import Adafruit_DHT

while True:

    humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(11, 4)

    print 'Temp: {0:0.1f} C  Humidity: {1:0.1f} %'.format(temperature, humidity)
```

Since I plan to use MySql and perhaps PHP, I then installed MySql and PHP5. I copied sshlog.py to a new file called envirolog.py. I had some trouble with PHPMysql, so I went back to the original *sshlog.py* and it fails:

```
pi@RPi0w-Logger:~ $ sudo python sshlog.py Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "sshlog.py", line 7, in <module>
    humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(11, 4)   
File "build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/Adafruit_DHT/common.py", line 94, in read_retry   
File "build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/Adafruit_DHT/common.py", line 80, in read   File "build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/Adafruit_DHT/common.py", line 55, in get_platform   
File "build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/Adafruit_DHT/Raspberry_Pi_2.py", line 22, in <module> 
ImportError: cannot import name Raspberry_Pi_2_Driver
```

Now I'm stuck. I did not change anything about the hardware. Did my install of MySql and PHP5 screw up Adafruit?

Comment: Can you still run AdafruitDHT.py? Have you tried to reinstall the package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went back and reinstalled the ADAFruit libraries. It worked. Dunno what I screwed up, but it was resolved by rerunning the install process.